# how to add number of visits to my to my blog in django

Tags: django, django-models

kindly help out i want to add code to counts anyone that read a specific blog should be counted, but the code i saw online wont work for me here is my model,please how do I go about it?

### models.py

```
class Blog(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    overview = models.TextField()
    categories = models.ManyToManyField(Category)
    timestamp = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    view_count = models.IntegerField(default = 0)
    doctor = models.ForeignKey(Doctor, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    image = models.ImageField()
    summary = models.TextField(max_length=150)][1]][1]
```

[image: here is the view count]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simple example — getting visit counts
As a simple real-world example we'll update our library to tell the current user how many times they have visited the LocalLibrary home page.

Open /locallibrary/catalog/views.py, and make the changes shown in bold below.

```
def index(request):
    ...

    num_authors = Author.objects.count()  # The 'all()' is implied by default.
    
    # Number of visits to this view, as counted in the session variable.
    num_visits = request.session.get('num_visits', 0)
    request.session['num_visits'] = num_visits + 1

    context = {
        'num_books': num_books,
        'num_instances': num_instances,
        'num_instances_available': num_instances_available,
        'num_authors': num_authors,
        'num_visits': num_visits,
    }
    
    # Render the HTML template index.html with the data in the context variable.
    return render(request, 'index.html', context=context)
```

### html

```
<p>You have visited this page {{ num_visits }}{% if num_visits == 1 %} time{% else %} times{% endif %}.</p>
```

**Note** this is an examplele from [Mozilla fireforx tutorial](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/Server-side/Django/Sessions)